# Rails belongs_to and has_many foreign_key relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need a little help... I have these relationships... Users belong to Department, a Department has a manager, Managers (Users) can have many managed departments.

I'm having one of those days and I can't for the life of me figure out what to put inside the `User` model to define the `has_many :managed_departments' part of the relationship.

**Department**

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :manager, foreign_key: "manager_id", class_name: "User"
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  # has_many :managed_departments
end
```

This works: `Department.last.manager` which returns:

```
=> #<User id: 2, etc...
```

I'm having a mindblank on what to put in the `User` model.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `class_name` option same like you used it in `Department` model

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  has_many :managed_departments, class_name: "Department", foreign_key: "manager_id"
end
```

Comment: Additionally, you should add the option `inverse_of: :manager`

Comment: I get ... : SELECT "departments".* FROM "departments" WHERE "departments"."user_id" = $1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column departments.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "departments".* FROM "departments" WHERE "departments...

Comment: @JamieBarton Totally forgot about that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating right association. You have many to many relation ship between user and department.

```
user has_many departments (Can manage multiple department)
department has_many users
```

As a database standard you should break many to many relationship and introduce a new intermediate table.

So your new table should be `users_departments`. In this table you can add column user is manager or not.

table should have column :
user_id , department_is, is_manager

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :users_departments
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departments, :through => :users_departments
end

class UsersDepartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :department
end
```

Here you can find anything with association. and with simple scope you can find manager of department also.

Comment: His model distinguishes between users and managers. Therefore he has this two-way relationship, which is absolutely correct.

Comment: Yeah a Department has_many users and a User belongs to a Department. It's not a HABTM relationship.

Comment: But manager is also a user entity. And an manager can manage multiple department. So it should be many to many.

Comment: Yeah but a department only has one manager. It works with the answer below. Thanks anyways!